# How to sort out all values of drop down list using Selenium (C#)

Tags: c#, selenium

could someone help with such task: I need to pick drop_down_1, select first option, then automatically in the another drop_down_2 the list with options will be shown, I have to select first option in drop_down_2, click button Get Results, after some time when the results will be shown to delete it and select the second option and so on and so forth. 
So, I need to iterate through each option of the drop_down_2 for each option of the drop_down_1.

Some html code below:

First drop down list with many options:

```
<select id="manufacturer-selector" data-bind="value: selectedManufacturer">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="5637148326">Nokia</option>
<option value="5637148327">Sony</option>
<option value="5637148328">Lenovo-new</option>
....
```

Second drop down list with many options:

```
<select id="product-selector" data-bind="attr: { disabled: countManufacturerProducts() === 0 }, foreach: manufacturerProducts, value: selectedProduct">
<option data-bind="text: Name, attr: { value: ID }" value="5637191581">390</option>
<option data-bind="text: Name, attr: { value: ID }" value="5637201719">390 Screenphone</option>
<option data-bind="text: Name, attr: { value: ID }" value="5637206334">470 Screenphone</option>47
```

Do I need to create a loop and inside it one more loop?

Answer (score 0):

first of all -- use selenium.support.ui

create 2 select elements

```
SelectElement select1 = driver.FindElement(By....);
SelectElement select2 = driver.FindElement(By....);
```

and after to count how much "option" elements in select 1.

```
var optionCounter1 = driver.FindElements(By...).Count;
var optionCounter2 = driver.FindElements(By...).Count;

for (int currOption1 =1; currOption1 < optionCounter; currOption1 ++)
{
    select1.SelectByIndex(currOption1 );

    for (int currOption2 =1; currOption2 < optionCounter; currOption2 ++)
    {
        select1.SelectByIndex(currOption1);
        select2.SelectByIndex(currOption2);
    }
}
```